# Last modified directories

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the get last modified directory in C# where it was modified by certain date it always get index 0 no matter what I try.  I do not understand why my code below is wrong.  Its today's date i debug it i get no results even though i modified the file today.

```
string dategiven = "";
dategiven  = DateTime.Now.ToString();


var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)
    .Where(d => new FileInfo(d).LastWriteTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(dategiven));
```

Comment: I think it's obvious we need to know what `dategiven` is in order to answer this question...why are you converting it to a date?  What's its data type?  What's the value after you convert it?

Comment: Did you debug that code? What happens? Do you find any directories? What is their `LastWriteTime` and is there any with a `LastWriteTime` greater than what `Convert.ToDateTime()` returns?

Comment: @Sammy please provide the example for `dategiven` you used for testing. If you really used `DateTime.Now.ToString()` it's obvious that there are no directories with _later_ access time than _now_.

Comment: oh i am so stupid i see where i my error is i needed to use datetime.today

Comment: Why are you converting `DateTime.Now` to string and then back to a date with `Convert.ToDateTime`?

Answer (score 2):

In example You provided You are trying to take files modified exact moment of creation datagiven variable or future. If You want files modified today just use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now` .

Answer (score 0):

Below works thanks guys I guess I need to debug to understand what was going on.

```
 string dategiven = "";
 dategiven  = DateTime.Today.ToString();


  var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)
.Where(d => new FileInfo(d).LastWriteTime >= Convert.ToDateTime(dategiven));
```